# Cant force urxvt load font, no matter what (unable to load base fontset)

Tags: linux, terminal, archlinux

I want to urxvt load `DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline` font, but it dont work with `xft` no matter what.

Excerpt from `~/.Xresources` [from my dotfiles](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/dotfiles/blob/painmode/Xresources#L70-L77)

```
! this work
! URxvt.font: -*-dejavu sans mono-medium-r-*-*-0-*-*-*-*-*-koi8-u

! none of these - dont
! URxvt.font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline:style=Book:size=12
! URxvt*font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline:style=Book:size=12
! URxvt*font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline:size=12
! URxvt*font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:size=12
```

I use [rxvt-unicode-patched](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rxvt-unicode-patched/) version from aur

Lets check if all right

```
$ urxvt --help 2>&1 | grep options                          
options: perl,styles,combining,blink,iso14755,unicode3,encodings=eu+vn+jp+jp-ext+kr+zh+zh-ext,fade,transparent,tint,pixbuf,XIM,frills,selectionscrolling,wheel,slipwheel,smart-resize,cursorBlink,pointerBlank,scrollbars=plain+rxvt+NeXT+xterm

$ fc-match "DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline" 
DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline" "Book"

$ fc-list G "DejaVu Sans Mono"
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSansMono.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVu Sans Mono Bold for Powerline.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVu Sans Mono Oblique for Powerline.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline:style=Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline:style=Book
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVu Sans Mono Bold Oblique for Powerline.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline:style=Bold Oblique
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Bold Oblique

$ xset q
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  660    repeat rate:  25
  auto repeating keys:  00fdffffdffffbbf
                        fedfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  4
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  600
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x22    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/TTF/,/usr/share/fonts/OTF/,/usr/share/fonts/Type1/,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Disabled

/etc/fonts/conf.d $ ll
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   44 Jan 10 11:07 10-hinting-slight.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-hinting-slight.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   48 Jan 10 11:07 10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   43 Jan 13 22:10 10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   47 Jan 13 22:10 11-lcdfilter-default.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/11-lcdfilter-default.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   46 Oct 31 11:34 20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans.conf -> ../conf.avail/20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   51 Oct 31 11:34 20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans-mono.conf -> ../conf.avail/20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans-mono.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   47 Oct 31 11:34 20-unhint-small-dejavu-serif.conf -> ../conf.avail/20-unhint-small-dejavu-serif.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   47 Jan 10 11:07 20-unhint-small-vera.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/20-unhint-small-vera.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   44 Jan 10 11:07 30-metric-aliases.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/30-metric-aliases.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   41 Jan 10 11:07 30-urw-aliases.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/30-urw-aliases.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Jan 12 20:08 31-cantarell.conf -> ../conf.avail/31-cantarell.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   38 Jan 10 11:07 40-nonlatin.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/40-nonlatin.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   40 Jun 16  2015 44-source-han-sans-kr.conf -> ../conf.avail/44-source-han-sans-kr.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Jan 10 11:07 45-latin.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/45-latin.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   39 Jan 10 11:07 49-sansserif.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/49-sansserif.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Jan 10 11:07 50-user.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/50-user.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Jan 10 11:07 51-local.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/51-local.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Oct 31 11:34 57-dejavu-sans.conf -> ../conf.avail/57-dejavu-sans.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   38 Oct 31 11:34 57-dejavu-sans-mono.conf -> ../conf.avail/57-dejavu-sans-mono.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Oct 31 11:34 57-dejavu-serif.conf -> ../conf.avail/57-dejavu-serif.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   35 Jan 10 11:07 60-latin.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/60-latin.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   43 Jan 10 11:07 65-fonts-persian.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/65-fonts-persian.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   38 Jan 10 11:07 65-nonlatin.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/65-nonlatin.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   37 Jan 10 11:07 69-unifont.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/69-unifont.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   39 Jan 10 11:07 80-delicious.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/80-delicious.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1565 Jan 12 22:26 81-ubuntu.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   39 Jan 10 11:07 90-synthetic.conf -> /etc/fonts/conf.avail/90-synthetic.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  978 Jan 10 11:07 README
```

what I get

```
$ xrdb -merge -I$HOME ~/.Xresources && urxvt
urxvt: unable to load base fontset, please specify a valid one using -fn, aborting.
```

`xrdb -query -all` at that time [here](http://pastebin.com/BaBGhuY1)

Why?!

Answer (score 1):

instead of size , you shoud use **pixelsize** :

```
URxvt.font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono for Powerline:style=Book:pixelsize=12
```

Comment: no, its not work, [xrdb -query -all at that time](http://pastebin.com/6dTQgn4N), also I have updated my question and include `xset q` at that time and my `/etc/fonts/conf.d`

Comment: I decided to comment [Xft related lines](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/dotfiles/blob/master/Xresources#L124-L127) because it can (I dont know how) clash with  `/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans-mono.conf`. Is it so?